# SOAP service client working in SOAPUI but not in Netbeans

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, netbeans-8, webservice-client

I have third-party web service, which I need to consume in my code. I have .wsdl file for that web service.

When I import that .wsdl file inside the SOAP UI and send the request I received a successful response but when I import the same WSDL inside the Netbeans and generate the client, the request sent successfully but when I parse the response I got null.

I am using stander way in Netbeans to generate the client. Screenshots are attached.

#### SOAP UI Screenshot

[image: SOAP UI Screenshot]

#### Source Code and Response

[image: Source Code and Response]

I don't know where i am doing wrong, any help really appreciated.

Comment: I had a problem that sounds similar to yours. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580220/soap-connection-timed-out-in-java-client-but-not-in-soapui). It could be a proxy problem.

Comment: Thank @WilliamBurnham for your reply. But my issue is different, as i am successfully able to connect with endPoint, like if don't add proper authentication i got unauthorize error, but when i provide all the required thing , it hit successfully, the only issue is in response, when i tried to get the response,it contain null values.