# java.net.UnknownHostException error in java (Parsing JSON data to String)

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am working on Parsing JSON data from a website then put in into a string.
When I tried it in my laptop using home internet, I could run it without any errors.
But when I tried to retype the code in my local PC in our office (corporate PC) then ran it, I am getting `java.UnknownHostException` error. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
`  try {
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        System.out.println(obj);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);

        }
        in.close();

        String final_response = response.toString();
        System.out.println(final_response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e);
    }`
```

Please do note that we have proxy.

Thank you to those who will answer.

Comment: You can try it using this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250600/proxy-settings-in-a-java-program

Comment: @Arian - Can you please check if the url is accessible from your office network. Since it's a get request, you can directly put that URL in browser and execute it. If you are not getting any response, it means it might be blocked by your office network.

Comment: Hi @Rohit the URL is accessible when i access it using a browser.

Comment: Hi guys, i finally found the answer. since my local PC uses a proxy, i just added this line : System.setProperty`("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");`

Answer (score 2):

i finally found the answer. since my local PC uses a proxy, i just added this line : `System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true")`;

reference: https://memorynotfound.com/configure-http-proxy-settings-java/

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to move the proxy configuration out of code and use specific attributes at runtime in the JVM configuration ( configure as environment based script if possible )

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=x.x.x.x -Dhttp.proxyPort=ZZZZ -jar fatJar.jar
```